# CKAN Data Set Errors

Tags: datastore, ckan

I installed CKAN and I am having difficulty with adding the DataStore extension using as a guide Setting Up the DataStore from the latest CKAN docs. When I get to the line 
`curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=_table_metadata"`, I get this reponse: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused`.

When I look at a dataset I created through the CKAN instance through my browser, the data preview on my JSON file shows an error:

[Dataset Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNTLe.jpg)

and trying to click the upper link to download the file directly also gives me a browser error when it goes to the URL:

[Browser Data Download Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34HKS.jpg)

I'm not sure what my next steps should be to figure out what's wrong but I think the FileStore is working since I was able to upload a picture and load it for an Organization listing.

The installation is fresh and has all the default settings from the installation guide so I haven't done any special modifications. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What is your `ckan.site_url` set to in your `prodution.ini`/`development.ini`?

Comment: `ckan.site_url = http://opendata.test`

Comment: This needs to be changed then. The `site_url` should be set to the URL under which your site is available. It is used for constructing URLs. So you probably need to change it to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` (assuming your ckan is running under that URL)

Comment: Hi k-nut, that seems to have done the trick. We weren't using `http://127.0.0.1:5000` but I used the address we have and it worked. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because k-nut's suggestion was the answer but it's in a comment to my question, I thought I'd post an official answer in case anyone else has the same problem. The `ckan.site_url` needs to be set to the specific URL that CKAN is running under which may not necessarily be a generic one, even if everything else is default configured. In my case, I have a specific internal URL for my VM that I needed to set.

Answer (score 0):

For me `ckan.site_url` was set to `http://demo.ckan.org` and `http://localhost`
took me to the CKAN page as specified in the installation tutorial, then I figured the port used was `8080` and not `5000` by going to `http://localhost:8080`.

So, I ended up using `curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=_table_metadata"` url instead.